How can I read JSON data in a variable with type of `types.Dynamic`?
I am writing a Custom Terraform Provider for Ansible Forms using the Terraform plugin framework (GitHub - hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework: A next-generation framework for building Terraform providers. v1.8.0). How can I read JSON string in a field with type types.Dynamic? The JSON string itself contains a map where values types are different.
Here is my DS model:
type JobDataSourceModel struct {
    CxProfileName types.String  `tfsdk:"cx_profile_name"`
    ...
    Extravars     types.Dynamic `tfsdk:"extravars"`
    ...
}

Here is the Schema() method:
func (d *JobDataSource) Schema(ctx context.Context, req datasource.SchemaRequest, resp *datasource.SchemaResponse) {
    resp.Schema = schema.Schema{
        Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute{
            ...
            "extravars": schema.DynamicAttribute{
                MarkdownDescription: "",
                Computed:            true,
            },
            ...
        },
    }
}

The Read() method:
func (d *JobDataSource) Read(ctx context.Context, req datasource.ReadRequest, resp *datasource.ReadResponse) {
    var data JobDataSourceModel
    ...
    data.Extravars = types.DynamicValue(restInfo.Data.Extravars)
    ...
}

Data returned by the Ansible Forms API is given below. The extravars field is a JSON string in the API response. I am converting a value of extravars into a map. Map values has diff types such as list, str, and boolean. That's why I want to use types.Dynamic.
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "job ran successfully",
    "data": {
        "id": 86,
        "form": "Demo Form Ansible No input",
        "target": "Demo Form Ansible No input",
        "status": "success",
        "start": "2024-05-02T15:35:16.000Z",
        "end": "2024-05-02T15:35:18.000Z",
        "user": "admin",
        "user_type": "local",
        "job_type": "ansible",
        "extravars": "{\"name\":\"vm1\",\"region\":\"myregion\",\"opco\":\"myopco\",\"svm_name\":\"mysvm_name\",\"exposure\":\"myexposure\",\"env\":\"myenv\",\"dataclass\":\"mydataclass\",\"share_name\":\"myshare_name\",\"accountid\":\"myaccountid\",\"size\":\"mysize\",\"protection_required\":\"myprotection_required\",\"ansibleforms_user\":{\"username\":\"admin\",\"id\":1,\"type\":\"local\",\"groups\":[\"local/admins\"],\"roles\":[\"public\",\"admin\"]},\"__playbook__\":\"dummy.yaml\",\"__inventory__\":\"\",\"__credentials__\":{\"vcenterCredentials\":\"VCENTER\"}}",
        "credentials": "{\"vcenterCredentials\":\"VCENTER\"}",
        "notifications": "{}",
        "approval": null,
        "step": null,
        "parent_id": null,
        "subjobs": null,
        "no_of_records": 45,
        "counter": 8,
        "output": "<span class='has-text-warning'>[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available</span> <span class='tag is-info is-light'>2024-05-02 15:35:17</span>\r\n<span class='has-text-warning'>[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that</span> <span class='tag is-info is-light'>2024-05-02 15:35:17</span>\r\n<span class='has-text-warning'>the implicit localhost does not match 'all'</span>\r\n<span class='has-text-warning'>[WARNING]: Found variable using reserved name: name</span> <span class='tag is-info is-light'>2024-05-02 15:35:17</span>\r\n\n<span class='has-text-weight-bold'>PLAY [This is a hello-world example] *******************************************</span> <span class='tag is-info is-light'>2024-05-02 15:35:17</span>\r\n\r\n<span class='has-text-weight-bold'>TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************</span>\r\n<span class='has-text-success'>ok: [localhost]</span> <span class='tag is-info is-light'>2024-05-02 15:35:18</span>\r\n\r\n<span class='has-text-weight-bold'>TASK [Output 'Welcome'.] *******************************************************</span>\r\n<span class='has-text-success'>ok: [localhost] => </span> <span class='tag is-info is-light'>2024-05-02 15:35:18</span>\r\n<span class='has-text-success'>  msg: Hi there and welcome to ansible</span>\r\n\r\n<span class='has-text-weight-bold'>PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************</span>\r\n<span class=''>localhost                  : <span class='tag is-success'>ok=2</span>    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0</span>\r\n<span class='has-text-success'>ok: [Playbook finished] with status (0)</span> <span class='tag is-info is-light'>2024-05-02 15:35:18</span>"
    }
}

I've tried doing that with the code abov, but it does not work.

why does it have to be Dynamic? that looks like a string to me on the return from ansible

Looking for example of terraform resources with similar json input, found this is one:
resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "deploy" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_account.demo
  ]
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.deploy.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.x.id
  stage_name    = "test"
  access_log_settings {
    destination_arn = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.logs.arn
    format          = "{ \"requestId\":\"$context.requestId\" }"
  }
}

see the format there is json data and in the code for that:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/internal/service/apigateway/stage.go#L56-L73
Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
    "access_log_settings": {
        Type:     schema.TypeList,
        MaxItems: 1,
        Optional: true,
        Elem: &schema.Resource{
            Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
                "destination_arn": {
                    Type:         schema.TypeString,
                    Required:     true,
                    ValidateFunc: verify.ValidARN,
                },
                "format": {
                    Type:     schema.TypeString,
                    Required: true,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    ...


... and if you need to read something from that json string use json.Unmarshal there are a lot of examples, here is one:
https://go.dev/play/p/zdMq5_ex8G

Thanks Helder, but the problem is that not every value is a string, but a boolean, lists, etc. Only the keys are strings

I do not follow ...  what is the problem with every value not been a string? ... your extravars is the string, and that string happens to be JSON, but we could care less what the values are json.Unmarshal takes care of that (as long as it is valid JSON)

The terraform-plugin-framework cares actually because when I create define a field as a map in the schema method it fails on boolean values coz it was meant to be have all the fields as strings. Btw, lemme check it again
